# How can I check whether a string represents a number in Elisp?

Tags: string, numbers

I want to check whether the string variable s is a number (integer or float) formatted as a string. I thought it could be done using `string-to-number` like this

```lisp
(defun string-number-base-p (s)
    (when (or (equal "0" s)
              (not (equal 0 (string-to-number s))))
      t))
```

but (as NickD pointed out) that also returns `t` for string-numbers with trailing characters like `"123zxyz"`.

Note that the built-in function `string-to-number` returns 0 instead of nil when it fails to convert a string, but also returns 0 for the string "0" which contains a valid number. Also, `string-to-number` considers `,` a non-number character and not a decimal or thousands separator, and will hence ignore everything from `,` when parsing. So `(string-to-number "2,3")` returns `2`.

Examples of valid number-strings include "0", "1", "-1", "1.3", and "4.3e10".

#### Comparison of answers

Based on the answers given, I've run some output and speed comparisons: see the table and code below. Notable is that the pure regex version is not slower than the other versions while being much more flexible: *To parse the strings in the header of the table 1 million times, the regex-based method took 13.6s, the read-based method 13.6s, and the imperfect base method 11.2s.*

| string-number | "0" | "1" | "-0" | "-1" | "+0" | "+1" | "01" | "-01" | "+01" | "2.3" | "-2.3" | "1.00" | "0.00" | "-0.00" | "00.00" | "-00.00" | "02.3" | ".0" | ".1" | "-.1" | "0." | "1." | "10." | "2,3" | ",0" | "0e0" | "2e5" | "2.3e5" | "-2.3e5" | "2.3e-5" | "2.3e03" | "2.3e0" | "0.01e4" | ".1e5" | "-.1e5" | "-.0e0" | "-0.0e10" | "2,3e5" | " " | "." | "-" | "-." | "b1" | "1b" | "2-3" | "3.4.5" | "4.,6" | "1,." | "e" | "-e" | "-.e" | ".e4" | "1e2-2" | "e2.3" | "e2.3.4" | "-e10" | "1e.-" | "10e." | "1\n" | "1\t" | "1 1" | "\n" | "\t" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -regex-p | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | nil | nil | nil | nil |
| -read-p | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | t | t | nil | nil |
| -read2-p | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | t | t | nil | nil |
| -read3-p | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | t | nil | nil | nil |
| -base-p | t | t | nil | t | nil | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | t | t | t | nil | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil | nil | nil | t | nil | nil | nil | t | t | t | t | t | nil | nil |

```lisp
(setq l (list "0" "1" "-0" "-1" "+0" "+1" "01" "-01" "+01" "2.3" "-2.3" "1.00"
              "0.00" "-0.00" "00.00" "-00.00" "02.3" ".0" ".1" "-.1" "0." "1."
              "10." "2,3" ",0" "0e0" "2e5" "2.3e5" "-2.3e5" "2.3e-5" "2.3e03"
              "2.3e0" "0.01e4" ".1e5" "-.1e5" "-.0e0" "-0.0e10" "2,3e5" " " "."
              "-" "-." "b1" "1b" "2-3" "3.4.5" "4.,6" "1,." "e" "-e" "-.e"
              ".e4" "1e2-2" "e2.3" "e2.3.4" "-e10" "1e.-" "10e." "1\n" "1\t"
              "1 1" "\n" "\t"))

(defconst string-number-regex
  (concat "^[+-]?\\(?:[0-9]+\\(?:[.,][0-9]*\\)?\\(?:e[+-]?[0-9]+\\)?"
          "\\|[.,][0-9]+\\(?:e[+-]?[0-9]+\\)?\\)$")
  "Matches integers and floats with exponent.
This allows for leading and trailing decimal point, leading zeros in base,
leading zeros in exponent, + signs, and , as alternative decimal separator.")

(defun string-number-regex-p (s)
  (when (string-match-p
         string-number-regex s)
    t))

(defun string-number-read-p (s)
  (condition-case _invalid-read-syntax
      (numberp (read s))
    (error nil)))

(defun string-number-read2-p (s)
  (when (and (string-match-p "[^ .,\t\n\r]" s)
             (numberp (read s)))
    t))

(cl-defun string-number-read3-p (str &key (test #'numberp))
  "Test whether STR is a string that contains one sexp of a certain type.
The type is identified by the TEST.
The default TEST is `numberp'."
  (and (stringp str)
       (string-match "\\S-" str) ;; not a whitespace string
       (condition-case nil
       (with-temp-buffer
         (insert str)
         (goto-char (point-min))
         (and (funcall test (read (current-buffer)))
          (looking-at "\\s-*\\'"))) ;; only whitespace up to eob
     (error nil))))

(defun string-number-base-p (s)
  (when (or (equal "0" s)
            (not (equal 0 (string-to-number s))))
    t))

(concat
 "| string-number | "
 (mapconcat (lambda (s) (concat "\"" s "\"")) l " | ")
 " |\n|---|"
 (mapconcat (lambda (s) "---") l "|")
 "|\n| -regex-p | "
 (mapconcat (lambda (s) (symbol-name (string-number-regex-p s))) l " | ")
 " |\n| -read-p | "
 (mapconcat (lambda (s) (symbol-name (string-number-read-p s))) l " | ")
 " |\n| -read2-p | "
 (mapconcat (lambda (s) (symbol-name (string-number-read2-p s))) l " | ")
 " |\n| -base-p | "
 (mapconcat (lambda (s) (symbol-name (string-number-base-p s))) l " | ")
 " |")
;; => table

(let ((reps 1000000))
  (list 
   (cons 'regex (benchmark-run-compiled reps (mapc #'string-number-regex-p l)))
   (cons 'read (benchmark-run-compiled reps (mapc #'string-number-read-p l)))
   (cons 'read2 (benchmark-run-compiled reps (mapc #'string-number-read2-p l)))
   (cons 'base (benchmark-run-compiled reps (mapc #'string-number-base-p l)))))
;; =>
;; ((regex 13.573386  0 0.0)
;;  (read  13.607431 81 4.161939)
;;  (read2 17.170425 14 0.739117)
;;  (base  11.242897 12 0.591818))
;; note: read3 is around 40 times slower, 
;; taking 58s for 100000 repetitions where the others take 1.4s

(let ((reps 1000000))
  (list 
   (cons 'regex (benchmark-run reps (mapc #'string-number-regex-p l)))
   (cons 'read (benchmark-run reps (mapc #'string-number-read-p l)))
   (cons 'read2 (benchmark-run reps (mapc #'string-number-read2-p l)))
   (cons 'base (benchmark-run reps (mapc #'string-number-base-p l)))))
;; =>
;; ((regex 13.58847  0 0.0)
;;  (read  15.86764 81 6.213117)
;;  (read2 17.26436 14 0.870470)
;;  (base  11.18225 12 0.565733))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string-match-p` can be used to check for numbers in a string STRING using the syntax `(string-match-p REGEXP STRING)` where REGEXP is a string holding a [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html). Note that `string-match-p` does not change match data, whereas `string-match` does.

Matching numbers (integers and floats) using regexes is quite involved in general, see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811031/decimal-or-numeric-values-in-regular-expression-validation) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)) for a great overview. A few examples are given below. To test them in the browser click the *test* link. To test them in Emacs use `M-x re-builder`.

In the (most of the) regexes below it is assumed that explicit plus signs `+` are not allowed. To allow them, change the parts of the regexes matching a `-` below (i.e. `-` except when part of a number range) to `[+-]`. Moreover, it is assumed that the decimal separator is `.`; to allow `,` too simply add it directly after all occurances of `.`. See (regex12) for an example. It is also assumed that signed zeros are allowed.

### Match only integers

positive integers ([test](https://regex101.com/r/ku1Up8/2)):

```lisp
"^\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)$" (regex1)
```

positive integers, allow leading zeros ([test](https://regex101.com/r/nVHO6U/1)):

```lisp
"^[0-9]+$" (regex2)
```

(positive or negative) integers ([test](https://regex101.com/r/MEeiUr/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)$" (regex3)
```

(positive or negative) integers, allow leading zeros ([test](https://regex101.com/r/SSwKTl/1)):

```lisp
"^-?[0-9]+$" (regex4)
```

### Match intergers and floats without exponent

integers and floats without exponents, allowing for leading decimal point ([test](https://regex101.com/r/ZsCghc/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:\\(?:\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)?[.][0-9]+\\)\\|\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)\\)$" (regex5)
```

integers and floats without exponents, allowing for leading decimal point, and allowing leading zeros ([test](https://regex101.com/r/qvctpd/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:[0-9]*[.]\\)?[0-9]+$" (regex6)
```

integers and floats without exponents, allowing for leading and trailing decimal point, and allowing leading zeros ([test](https://regex101.com/r/iV6zCB/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:[0-9]+\\(?:[.][0-9]*\\)?\\|[.][0-9]+\\)$" (regex7)
```

### Match integers and floats with exponent ([scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation))

integers and floats with exponent, allowing for leading decimal point ([test](https://regex101.com/r/DUVIGf/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:\\(?:\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)?[.][0-9]+\\)\\|\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)\\)\\(?:e-?\\(?:0\\|[1-9][0-9]*\\)?\\)?$" (regex8)
```

integers and floats with exponent, allowing for leading decimal point, leading zeros in base, and leading zeros in exponent ([test](https://regex101.com/r/rg7FAj/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:[0-9]*[.]\\)?[0-9]+\\(?:e-?[0-9]+\\)?$" (regex9)
```

integers and floats with exponent, allowing for leading decimal point, leading zeros in base, and overly permissive exponent (this is `eshell-number-regexp` surrounded with `^` and `$` and using shy groups) ([test](https://regex101.com/r/Nqk5FK/1)):

```lisp
"^-?\\(?:[0-9]*[.]\\)?[0-9]+\\(?:e[-0-9.]+\\)?$" (regex10)
```

integers and floats with exponent, allowing for leading and trailing decimal point, leading zeros in base, and leading zeros in exponent ([test](https://regex101.com/r/bWe05v/1)):

```lisp
"^[-]?\\(?:[0-9]+\\(?:[.][0-9]*\\)?\\(?:e[-]?[0-9]+\\)?\\|[.][0-9]+\\(?:e[-]?[0-9]+\\)?\\)$" (regex11)
```

integers and floats with exponent, allowing for leading and trailing decimal point, leading zeros in base, leading zeros in exponent, `+` signs, and `,` as alternative decimal separator ([test](https://regex101.com/r/5Gikyu/1)):

```lisp
"^[+-]?\\(?:[0-9]+\\(?:[.,][0-9]*\\)?\\(?:e[+-]?[0-9]+\\)?\\|[.,][0-9]+\\(?:e[+-]?[0-9]+\\)?\\)$" (regex12)
```

Comment: Yes, some kind of regex would do it. I added some examples of what are valid number-strings, and your answer works for only some.

Comment: The question has been modified from the initial example of an integer, to now an integer / float / scientific, ....  A moving target becomes somewhat difficult to answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I though a "number" is a general term and not necessarily an integer.

Comment: I will keep the answer posted for the time being, pending something better by another forum participant, but I am changing `string-match` to `string-match-p` (which does not change the match data).

Comment: For easy reference, I expanded the post with regexes covering many cases, as regexes found elsewhere on stackexchange often include lookarounds and other non-Emacs syntax, plus they have to be quoted.

Comment: Beware of using regexes allowing `,` as a decimal separator if you not only want to check for a number, but want to parse it too using `sting-to-number`. `sting-to-number` doesn't consider `,` a decimal separator and will instead truncate the number at `,` when parsing. This applies to regex12. Regex 1-11 seem to match only numbers which are correctly parsed by `string-to-number`.

Answer (score 2):

the `read` function can be applied to a  string and then the `numberp` function tests whether the read object represents a number or not, integer, or float.

```
(mapcar (lambda(x)(numberp(read x))) (list "123" "1.23" "sqrt(123)" "12e-3" "12ab3"))
```

=>

```
 (t t nil t nil)
```

You catch any error with this function

```
(defun string-numberp(s)
  (condition-case invalid-read-syntax
      (numberp(read s))
    (error nil)))
```

Test :

```
(mapcar #'string-numberp  (list "12345" "12.345" "#12345" "." "," "\n"))
```

=>

```
(t t nil nil nil nil)
```

Comment: Nice, this works well, but will throw an error for strings like `"."`, `","`, or `"\n"`.

Comment: I added a function that is supposed to trap any invalid read syntax error. I haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it a bit. It suppresses wanted errors when passed things like `'10` and even does very bad things when passed things like `'kill-line`... In my comparison above I also tried a variant `string-number-read2-p` which seems to work well, but I don't know if it catches all input problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use `read`. It just does the right job with regard to Elisp.
But, do not use it on strings because `read` only reads the first sexp.
You must be able to test what follows by checking the text from the next read position. That is only possible by reading from a buffer, e.g. a temporary one.

You have also to protect against expressions that cannot be read, e.g., by `condition-case`.

The following example code contains some tests as comments at the end.

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(cl-defun string-test-p (str &key (test #'numberp))
  "Test whether STR is a string that contains one sexp of a certain type.
The type is identified by the TEST.
The default TEST is `numberp'."
  (and (stringp str)
       (string-match "\\S-" str) ;; not a whitespace string
       (condition-case nil
       (with-temp-buffer
         (insert str)
         (goto-char (point-min))
         (and (funcall test (read (current-buffer)))
          (looking-at "\\s-*\\'"))) ;; only whitespace up to eob
     (error nil))))
;; Test:
;; (string-test-p " 1.23 ") ;; Returns t.
;; (string-test-p "'kill-line") ;; Returns nil. This is no problem because the string is read but not evaluated.
;; (string-test-p "(kill-line)") ;; Returns nil. This is no problem because the string is read but not evaluated.
;; (string-test-p " \"string\" " :test #'stringp) ;; Returns t.
;; (string-test-p " kill-line " :test #'functionp) ;; Returns t.
;; (string-test-p " (unfinished list ") ;; Returns nil.
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this to the comparison table as `string-number-read3-p`, it has good parsing properties, but offers no flexibility as to what counts as a number and is around 40 times slower than the other answers.

Comment: @orgtre Yes, it is tailored to read numbers from strings that are appropriate for the Elisp reader.

Comment: Is that the same as "numbers in strings that are correctly parsed by `string-to-number`"? That would be useful, since many times when checking for a number, you actually want to parse it too. With the regex approach one risks matching numbers which won't be parsed correctly.

Comment: @orgtre `string-to-number` is essentially what is used by the Elisp reader ([`string_to_number` in `lread.c`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/281f48f19ecad706a639d57cb937afb0b97eded7/src/lread.c#L4480)). So `read` reads the same as `string-to-number` if the string can be read as number.

Comment: @orgtre Note the call to `string_to_number` at the end of the [definition of `string-to-number`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/281f48f19ecad706a639d57cb937afb0b97eded7/src/data.c#L3059)`.